# detect when previous song/ next song on a multimedia player is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I want to detect when I press on a bluetooth multimedia player play/pause, previous song, next song buttons.

I want to know if it is possible. I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start. I have searched for the past 2 hours but haven't found anything. I'm new to HTML and Javascript.

Comment: We need more context. Is this 'bluetooth multimedia player' controlled via your browser?

Comment: No, it is literally a bluetooth multimedia player controller, like even on wireless head buds etc you can control with touch, like you can control spotify by touching your wireless head buds, idk if airpods have this function most probably they do

Comment: Then no, that's not possible via HTML/JS

Comment: Okay, thank you. Do you know any alternative? I want to detect volume up and down at least. I was thinking about using the accessibility talkback feature

Comment: No, that's not possible at the OS-level. HTML/JS can only access media playing within the browser via the audio/video elements, not played through external programs.

Comment: Hey, I have tested on open spotify and it detects when I use touch controls to pause the music. Do you know how they do it? Most probably they don't use JS

Comment: They are using JS, but they can control the media because it's being played either through the browser, or via requests to a central server which can be used to control their program installed on another machine. As you do not have that server-side infrastructure or even that level of access to a third-party media player, you will not be able to recreate Spotify's behaviour.

Comment: But how do they know when you pressed the pause button on the wireless head bud? That's what I want to detect

Comment: Are you talking JUST about controlling Spotify? If so they have a public API you can use: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/skip-users-playback-to-next-track. If you are talking about controlling ANY media, then that's not possible for the reasons I've outlined in previous comments.